# Issue with unique font names, are scripts required?

Tags: css, html, fonts

trying to change my header 1's font to ballpark Weiner.

Below is my css:

```
h1 {color: #000000; font-family: Ballpark Weiner; 
        font-size: 40px;
}
```

Trying to get the font to look like this:

http://www.fontgirl.com/info/ballpark.php

It ends up looking like a Arial type of font. For unqiue fonts like this, are there scripts required to be inserted? If a screen shot is needed for current font please let me know.

Comment: did you include the @font-face in the stylesheet?

Comment: `To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens` http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the link you provided, and this is how you should to it.

Go to [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and upload your **BALLW___.TTF** file, 
and it will generate the other font extensions that you need + the fontface rules
the font-face rules would look something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontname';
    src: url('fontname-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontname-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fontname-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fontname-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fontname-webfont.svg#fontname') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

include that in your css file
then you can use that like this

```
css selector
{
font-family: 'fontname';
}
```

ps: dont forget to upload your fonts

Comment: Funny how I actually still forgot to upload my fonts! It worked perfect. Thanks for the perfect explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this code to work with your font and add it to your CSS file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: cool_font;
    src: url('cool_font.ttf'); // link to the font
}
```

then when you want to use it just do this

```
p.custom_font {
    font-family: cool_font; // no .ttf
}
```